# String to DateTime Convert Issue

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-parsing

Hi I have a string in following format `23/03/2014`  and I have tried to convert it to this format:

```
string npacked = Convert.ToDateTime(packeddate).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

But I am getting an error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Also tried this:

```
string npacked = DateTime.Parse(packeddate).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

but same error.

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`? Do you want as a result `2014/03/23`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with `ParseExact` with the format

```
string npacked = DateTime.ParseExact(packeddate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

**[DEMO](https://ideone.com/2NU9wy)**

Comment: debug and check the value you have for `packeddate`

Comment: Its 23/03/2014 getting

Comment: Not sure if its important, but the MSDN example for "ParseExact" also uses the French culture for this kind of conversion.

Comment: This worked for me. Double check the included demo.
"Not working getting error" => Please describe the error.

Answer (score 1):

Convert.ToDateTime is running a DateTime.Parse() on your string (23/03/2014). In the default culture (en-US) that is going to fail, since dates in that culture should be formatted MM/DD/YYYY. You need to switch to a different culture (like French) per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
  // Reverse month and day to conform to the fr-FR culture. 
  // The date is February 16, 2008, 12 hours, 15 minutes and 12 seconds.
  dateString = "16/02/2008 12:15:12";
  try {
     dateValue = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
     Console.WriteLine("'{0}' converted to {1}.", dateString, dateValue);
  }   
  catch (FormatException) {
     Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}'.", dateString);
  }

  // Call another overload of Parse to successfully convert string 
  // formatted according to conventions of fr-FR culture.       
  try {
     dateValue = DateTime.Parse(dateString, new CultureInfo("fr-FR", false));
     Console.WriteLine("'{0}' converted to {1}.", dateString, dateValue);
  }   
  catch (FormatException) {
     Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}'.", dateString);
  }
```

Calling "ToString" afterwards has no effect whatsoever on the parse attempt, it just formats the output of the parse.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to your system date time format. You have `mm-dd-yyyy` format in your system and you are trying to parse it in `dd-mm-yyyy` format. Try changing your system date format to `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Answer (score 0):

[`Convert.ToDateTime(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) calls [`DateTime.Parse(string, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explicitly. That means your both lines are equivalent.

In your profile, it says you are from Dubai, United Arab Emirates. That's why I assume your `CurrentCulture` is probably `ar-AE` at first but your string matches it's [`ShortDatePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and that's why it prints;

```
Convert.ToDateTime("23/03/2014", new CultureInfo("ar-AE")) // 23/03/2014
```

But you didn't tell us what is your `CurrentCulture`, we never know.. But looks like your current culture's date seperator is not `/` or your current culture doesn't have standart date format `dd/MM/yyyy` (which is unlikely for most of cultures) your both lines fail (first scenario is more likely).

You can easly parse your string with a culture that has `/` as a [`DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) using [`DateTime.ParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This method let's you specify your custom date formats. We can use [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example;

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("23/03/2014",
                               "dd/MM/yyyy",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now, let's consider to it's representation with `yyyy/MM/dd` format.

[`/` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning of "*replace me with the current culture's date separator*" in custom date formats. That means if your date seperator is not `/` (I assume it is not) your `date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")` results will be included your date seperator, not `/`.

For example, I'm from Turkey, my culture is `tr-TR`. My date seperator is `.` (dot) That's why this example;

```
date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"); // Prints 2014.03.23 not 2014/03/23
```

In such a case, you can use a culture which has `/` a date seperator as a second parameter in your `ToString` method (`InvariantCulture` for example) like;

```
date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) // Prints 2014/03/23
```

or you can escape your `/` character regardless which culture you use like;

```
date.ToString(@"yyyy\/MM\/dd") // Prints 2014/03/23
```